# Como somar campos de um alias criando nova coluna alias?

Tags: sql, sql-server, query

Estou realizando uma consulta para calcular o valor de ST dos produtos, porém quando tento calcular os valores da coluna "total", não sei como fazer.

```
    select cdg_produto, val_base_icms_origem, pct_aliq_icms, 
    sum((val_base_icms_origem * pct_aliq_icms) / 100) as total
    from bdodnfe
    where cdg_filial = 5
    and nmr_docto = 5687386
    and dcr_serie = "11"
    group by cdg_produto, val_base_icms_origem, pct_aliq_icms
```

Desta forma, preciso ter a soma da coluna "total".

Comment: Por favor, esclareça seu problema ou forneça detalhes adicionais a fim de destacar exatamente o que você precisa. Da forma como está escrito atualmente é difícil dizer com exatidão o que você está perguntando.

Comment: não entendi seu problema; a query está certa? o que significa usar o "total"?

Comment: pq não transforma a query numa sub-query, assim por exemplo `select sum(total) from (select ... aqui vai o select que já tem) as sub`

Comment: Deu certo, obrigado! Sou iniciante e estou estudando